# Dependency error received on create-app command:

Tags: grails

When using create-app command on cygwin, following dependencies error is received. My system has Windows 7, 64 bit, Grails 2.2.5, Java 1.6.0_45. Any pointers or guidance will be greatly appreciate :) Thanks!

$ grails create-app testCreateApp

| Loading Grails 2.2.5
| Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1

```
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1!commons-fileupload.jar:

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs/lib/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5/lib/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/ivy-1.3.1.xml

      -- artifact commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1!commons-fileupload.jar:

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5/lib/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/jars/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5/lib/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/bundles/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5\src\libs/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.xml

      -- artifact commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1!commons-fileupload.jar:

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5\src\libs/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5\dist/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.xml

      -- artifact commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1!commons-fileupload.jar:

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5\dist/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\raishs\.grails\2.2.5\cached-installed-plugins/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.xml

      -- artifact commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1!commons-fileupload.jar:

      C:\Users\raishs\.grails\2.2.5\cached-installed-plugins/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5/plugins/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.pom

      -- artifact commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1!commons-fileupload.jar:

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5/plugins/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1

```
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1!commons-fileupload.jar:

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs/lib/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5/lib/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/ivy-1.3.1.xml

      -- artifact commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1!commons-fileupload.jar:

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5/lib/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/jars/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5/lib/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/bundles/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5\src\libs/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.xml

      -- artifact commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1!commons-fileupload.jar:

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5\src\libs/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5\dist/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.xml

      -- artifact commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1!commons-fileupload.jar:

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5\dist/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\raishs\.grails\2.2.5\cached-installed-plugins/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.xml

      -- artifact commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1!commons-fileupload.jar:

      C:\Users\raishs\.grails\2.2.5\cached-installed-plugins/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5/plugins/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.pom

      -- artifact commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1!commons-fileupload.jar:

      C:\cygwin64\home\raishs\.gvm\grails\2.2.5/plugins/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: commons-fileupload#commons-fileupload;1.3.1: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1

Comment: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11088 might be of use

Comment: Thanks Vahid!! 

I downloaded commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar into the lib folder and it seemed to have solved the problem.